# Select rows with same value as given ID

Tags: mysql, sql

my table looks like this:

```
ID  |  Name      | file | 
=========================
1   |  test1     |   pdf   
2   |  test1     |   pdf   
3   |  test2     |   pdf   
4   |  test3     |   jpg
```

I want all entries with the same name as the given ID. E.g. my function gets id=1 i want all entries with the same name as ID 1.

My approach so far:

```
select yt1.*
    from table yt1
    left outer join table yt2
    on (yt1.doc_name = yt2.doc_name)
    where yt1.id = '.$docId.'
    ;
```

But of course i'll only get one entry. How can i do that with mySQL?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Comment: Your query would work if you used `select yt2.*` instead of `select yt1.*`.

Comment: ...and it would be neater than any of the other solutions (so far) provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from mytable 
where name in (
   select name from mytable
   where id = '.$docId.'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could push it to the where clause... I believe this will work:

SELECT
    yt1.*
FROM
    table yt1
WHERE
    yt1.ID IN 
        (SELECT
            yt1.ID
        FROM
            table yt1
        WHERE
            yt1.doc_name = '.$docId.')